# Change Maximum Number of Columns in Sqlite3 from Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to increase the column limit of sqlilte3 database using SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN. Is there a way to change it inside a python script instead of directly accessing the source code of sqlite3?
https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: The default of 2000 isn't enough? What the heck are you doing? Anyways, like it says, you'll have to compile your own version of sqlite with a new maximum. It's not something you can increase at run time.